# Error in Discord.js v12 message sending toa specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello everyone reading i hope you guys having a nice day, recently i started working on a discord bot one of the features would be sending a message to a specific channel when needed. Here is the code to it

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../config.json');
const { client } = require('../index.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); 

module.exports = async (bot, jsonMsg, position) => {
    fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${(jsonMsg.extra && jsonMsg.text == 'Guild > ' && (jsonMsg.extra[1].text == 'left.' || jsonMsg.extra[1].text == 'joined.')) ? jsonMsg.extra[0].text.replace(/[ ]/g, '') : "steve"}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
 
    let uuid = data.id ? data.id : "8667ba71b85a4004af54457a9734eed7" // Defaults to the steve skin UUID if not found
    //const gchannel = client.channels.cache.get('817842919561232445'); // The guild channel
    const gchannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "817842919561232445")
    
    
    
    // Join embed
    const joinEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(config.GREEN)
    .setAuthor(`${jsonMsg.extra ? jsonMsg.extra[0].text : null}is now online.`, `https://crafatar.com/avatars/${uuid}.png`);
    // Leave embed
    const leaveEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(config.RED)
    .setAuthor(`${jsonMsg.extra ? jsonMsg.extra[0].text : null}is now offline.`, `https://crafatar.com/avatars/${uuid}.png`);
    // If Message starts with guild
    if (jsonMsg.text == 'Guild > ' && jsonMsg.extra[1].text == 'left.') {
        gchannel.send(leaveEmbed);
    } else if (jsonMsg.text == 'Guild > ' && jsonMsg.extra[1].text == 'joined.') {
        gchannel.send(joinEmbed);
    }

    if (jsonMsg.extra) {
        if (jsonMsg.text == '' && jsonMsg.extra[0].text.startsWith('§2Guild > ')) {
            // Guild messages have the color codes built in, opposed to join messages, so we have to get rid of those.
            let username = jsonMsg.extra ? jsonMsg.extra[0].text.replace('§2Guild > ', '').replace(/§7/g, '').replace(/§f/g, '').replace(/§3/g, '').replace(/§a/g, '').replace(/§6/g, '').replace(/§b/g, '').replace(/§d/, '').replace(/§c/g, '').replace(/§d/g, '').replace(/§e/g, '').replace(/§1/g, '').replace(/§0/g, '').replace(/§2/g, '').replace(/§4/g, '').replace(/§5/g, '').replace(/§8/g, '').replace(/§9/g, '').replace('[VIP] ', '').replace('[VIP+]', '').replace('[MVP]', '').replace('[MVP+]', '').replace('[MVP++]', '').replace('[P]', '').replace('[DGD]', '').replace('[GM]', '').replace('[BG]', '').replace('[EX]', '').replace('[GD]', '').replace(' :', '') : null;
            // Fetch the message (if it exists)
            let msg = jsonMsg.extra ? jsonMsg.extra[1].text : null;

            // Detects if username fetch and message fetch were sucessful
            if (username !== null && msg !== null) {
                // Used to get the player's uuid for the image using the username
                fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${username.replace(/[ ]/g, '')}`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(p => {
                // Message Embed
                const messageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(config.GREEN)
                .setAuthor(username, `https://crafatar.com/avatars/${p.id}.png`)
                .setDescription(msg)
                .setFooter("Phazence Discord to Hypixel bridge bot")
                .setTimestamp();
                gchannel.send(messageEmbed);
                })
                // Test command used inside the guild
                // Activated by '/gc /ping'
                if (msg.toLowerCase() == '!botping') {
                    bot.chat(`/gc Pong! Latency is ${bot.player.ping}ms.`);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    })
}
```

For some reason i keep getting Type Errors
ERROR:

```
(node:36) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at /home/container/mineflayer/message.js:52:26
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:36) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:36) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried replacing the gchannel constant many times to different methods of fetching the channel but that didnt seem to help dont know what happend or how to fix it.
Thanks beforehand :D

Comment: Could you specify which line number is causing the issue in your code? and only display that part of the code thats going wrong - it would make debugging infinitely easier.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the channel ID is correct
2. Try logging the "gchannel" just next to where it is defined.
3. Try passing the "client" using the parameters instead of requiring it.